# Swing MigLayout - Shrinking a label when there isn't enough space

Tags: java, swing, layout, constraints, miglayout

I have tried making a label automatically shrink, so that for example:

`This is text` becomes `This i...`

However, i was unable to achieve this.

My layout looks like the following:

```
JPanel container = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().fillX().gridGapX("2")));
container.add(new JXTitledSeparator("Text"), new CC().growX().spanX().wrap());

JLabel shrinkMeIfYouNeedTo = new JLabel("Shrink Shrink");
container.add( shrinkMeIfYouNeedTo, new CC());
container.add( infoText,  new JLabel("Great, long, beautiful info text that shall never shrink"), new CC().growX().spanX().wrap());

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(container);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

I already tried using `shrinkX` and `shrinkPrioX`, but none of them had an effect, neither did `minWidth("1")` have an effect.

Comment: Using just spanX() instead of growX doesnt works?

Comment: No, because spanX() causes a cell to take up the rest of a row, which ain't what i need.

Comment: So using only growX instead of spanX?

Comment: I do want the second component to grow, so i obviously need to use growX() and i also want it to span the whole width. the problem is just the first component not wanting to shrink.

Comment: Sorry it is a really late answer, but what I posted should allow you to accomplish what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't include everything as I don't have SwingX and I don't know what `infoText` is. But I got the impression you were after this sort of behaviour:

[image: Full Size]

[image: Starting To Shrink]

[image: Minimum Size]

If you are, it is achieved by setting the minimum width and preferred width to 0, and the maximum to whatever you like. With `String` component constraints, you would do it like `width 0:0:100`.

---

**Runnable Example**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel container = new JPanel(new MigLayout("fill, gapx 2", "grow"));
        container.add(new JLabel("Header", SwingConstants.CENTER), "split, span, growx, wrap");

        JLabel shrinkMeIfYouNeedTo = new JLabel("Shrink Shrink");
        container.add( shrinkMeIfYouNeedTo, "growx, width 0:0:100");
        container.add( new JLabel("Great, long, beautiful info text that shall never shrink"), "growx");

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(container);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 100));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I probably figured it out already (God only knows, but thanks, it looks correct).

Anyways, i'd like to suggest not to use the String API of MigLayout, as you loose all the compiletime safety ;)